# What does $this generally mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I am really new to PHP, so I am kind of confused seeing these different operators all day. Here is some code I came across when watching a video tutorail, I'd appreciate it if some could explain a little bit:

```
class Email extends CI_Controller
{
 function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

   function index()
    {
    $config = Array(
        'protocol'    => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port'  => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'username@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' =>'password',
    );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('username@gmail.com', 'Jerry');
        $this->email->to('username@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('this is an email test');
        $this->email->message('this is test message!');

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo 'Your email was sent';
        }
        else 
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Always nice to see comments deleted for no valid reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, function index is part of a class. The index function is accessing other objects that are member values of the same class. In order to access those member values, you have to use the pseudo-variable $this. $this refers to the object you are currently in.

For exmaple:

```
$this->email->subject('this is an email test');
```

Translated: Call the "subject function" from the email object, which is a member of this object.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [PHP documentation for classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

Answer (score 3):

Well you probably let out some important parts from the code you pasted. It's probably used in a class..
It means a reference to itself. So if you have a class with a load() function. Calling `$this->load()` from within the class will load that class function.

Comment: Thanks for reminding that, that was indeed a fatal omission :)

Answer (score 2):

`$this` refers to the instance of the class in which the function appears. So whatever class the above `index()` function appears in it, when you create an instance of it and call `myObject.index()`, `$this` will refer to `myObject`.

Answer (score 0):

$this means the current instance of the class where the called method was defined.